# How to convert Arrays into Strings

Tags: php, arrays, database, string, converters

I am trying to make my own website, but I have a litle problem. 
 I've created a database so save some contact informations (like street, city, contact phone...)
and I am getting these informations as arrays. 
 It would be awesome if you guys could help me figure out, how I can sort the arrays, or at least seperate them. 

 
I think it would be a good idea to work with strings, but i cannot convert them.
Currently I am using this right here:

```
$details = array('street', 'city','state', 'zipcode', 'location_name', 'country', 'date_created', 'contact_phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $details);

echo $comma_separated;
```

$details is the array with all of the info.

 I am thankfull for every help :D

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have posted? It looks perfectly valid to me.

Comment: Why can't you just access the data points you want from the array?

Comment: What *exactly* is the problem you are having here?  Your code will create a comma-separated string.  Is that not what you want?  What are you trying to do?  I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: What output you got ? Is there any error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, the result should look like : `"street,city,state,zipcode,location_name,country,date_created,contact_phone"`,

but if you want to get this informations separately, you have to stock each elements in variable, like

```
$data_street = $details[0];
```

this variable contain the first element of the array $details, so if you echo $data_street, you can show this :

```
street
```

and with an another value :

```
$data_state = $details[2];
```

$data_state return :

```
state
```

look : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for you:

```
<?php
// define string
$str = array('tinker ', 'tailor' , 'soldier' , 'spy');
echo implode(" ",$str);
?>
```

Output will be:

```
tinker tailor soldier spy
```

Comment: <?php // array to string $arr_join = array('tailor', 'soldier', 'spy'); $separater = join(",", $arr_join); echo $separater; ?> this can be alternative to implode command join tailor,soldier,spy will be output

Comment: <?php
$str = array('tinker','tailor','soldier','spy');

foreach($str as $val)
echo " ".$val;
?>